# Does the goinstant api handle reconnecting if the connection is lost?

Tags: goinstant

Does the goinstant connection automatically handle reconnection in case of disconnection?

I can't find any indication of this in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GoInstant reconnects automatically, but that appears to be a hole in our documentation.

Internally, the GoInstant client implements a capped Fibonacci back-off sequence (in milliseconds):

```
[100,100,200,300,500,800,1300,2100,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000]
```

Each time the connection drops, that sequence of reconnects is attempted.  Once it reaches the end of that sequence (approx 41 seconds later), the connection is considered dead and you get a `goinstant.ConnectionError` object passed via the `.on('error')` event of the `Connection` object.

The error classes are documented here: https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/javascript_api/connection/errors.html